# How long can I let an IPA fermented while dry hopping?

Tags: specific-gravity

The hydrometer reading is 1.014 from 1.058.  I just dry hopped.  How long should I let it ferment?  Can I let alone for one more week without messing it up?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted knowledge on dry hopping today is as so:

- The majority of the hop aroma will be imparted after 24 hours.
- Nearly all of the hop aroma will be imparted after 72 hours.
- Vegetal and other off flavours will begin to develop after 2 weeks.
- Hop pellets are more efficient for dry hopping than whole hops*.

*I spoke with Charles Faram about this and was told that T90 pellets are around 15% more efficient at utilization than whole hops meaning you'd need 15% less weight of pellets as you would whole hops to achieve the same aroma and flavour.

I will usually dry hop for 3-5 days.

To answer your question, you will be fine leaving it for 1 week.